# Inconsistent Results in FQL Stream Table with IN clause

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm having issues getting an FQL query to work with an IN clause for multiple pages. The pages are publicly accessible - so I'm not sure if there a permission issue or not

Ex:

```
SELECT post_id, source_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id in (40796308305, 56381779049) order by updated_time;
```

This is using the graph api explorer with all the permissions enabled. I will either get no data, or just simply a few posts from the last graphid specified in the IN clause.

Thoughts? This doesn't seem to be well documented in the FQL documentation.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can pass an array of ids to `source_id`. You'll probably need to do this as a series of queries.

Comment: Unfortunately individual queries are inefficient and slows down my page load time considering the large number of queries I might need on occasions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a multiquery. You'll get all your data in one shot. You will need to sort the results together in your script to get these into chronological order.

```
{
  "coke":"SELECT post_id, source_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = 40796308305 order by updated_time",
  "pepsi":"SELECT post_id, source_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = 56381779049 order by updated_time"
 }
```